# Looking for information on PARADISE (software)

Tags: analysis, engines, middlegame, patterns

I am working on developing statistics around the middlegame. During searching I found a little information about PARADISE (PAttern Recognition Applied to DIrecting SEarch), which was developed by Wilkins in 1980. Do you know anything about PARADISE? Or do you know any similar software? I will appreciate any kind of answer which helps me dig deeper.

Answer (score 2):

A very informative article about PARADISE was published by Wilkins himself  in "Artificial Intelligence, Volume 14, Number 2" (September 1980), which I was lucky to get my hands on years ago when I was writing my diploma thesis on chess programming and kept it since then.
Unfortunately, it is rather difficult to get at these days. But the article should have been reprinted in "Computer Chess Compendium", by D. Levy, which still appears to be available: [Abe Books](http://www.abebooks.com/search/sortby/3/an/David+Levy+/tn/+Compendium)
Other than that, I was only able to dig out some working notes related to the program (written in a dialect of Lisp) again by Wilkins himself, which also apparently contains some program fragments: [Working notes on Paradise chess patterns](http://www.ai.sri.com/pubs/files/465.pdf)
Should you stumble upon additional sources, please keep us informed.